# Display a alert box in ASP.net c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert

I want to display a alert message when a user clicks on button.

I have a button "`Signed`" on click of this button I want to display a alert message saying "`Are you sure you want to continue?`" and two buttons in this alert message box "`Yes`" and "`No`".

On click of yes button I want a `update function` to be executed and on click of "`No`" only Alert should get closed and no changes in the current page.

Please anyone can guide me how to go on with this?

Comment: use javascript or jquery for this purpose

Comment: +1 to the idea of using JS or jQuery

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about javascript or jquery. Can you help me out with any tutorials online for beginners? how do i use it with ASP.net? thank you @Nighil

Comment: have you checked out messagebox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the OnClientClick on the button for this.
Add a return confirm(); to it. It will create a javascript confirm dialog, BEFORE it fires the click event.
If the user presses no, it will not trigger the OnClick event.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');"
```

So, added to your button markup, it would look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Signed" Visible="False" onclick="Button5_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');" />
```

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Signed" Visible="False" 
                    onclick="Button5_Click" /> this is my button code. where do i add the above code you mentioned?in a class file for buttonclick event?

Comment: Just add the code i printed, inside your button tag. It will fire before your Button5_Click, and Button5_Click will then only fire, if the users presses yes.

Answer (score 1):

jquery should do for you.

```
$("#ButtonId").click({
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to continue");
})
```